# Python Search a text file for keyword and print the associated line for multiple keywords

Tags: python, text-extraction

I'm trying to search a .txt file that contains a lot of extraneous information for just a few keywords that contain the most important information. I would like to find the words and print out the line that word is in.

I'm fairly new to python and thought I had it figured out but I don't know how to scale my current code for multiple keywords.

```
fileName = input("Paste file name here")

with open(fileName) as inputFile:
    data = inputFile.readlines()
    inputFile.close()

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    searchPhrase1 = input("what phrase are you looking for?")
    if searchPhrase1 in line:
        for l in data[i:i:3]:
            print (l)
print
```

Comment: `if searchPhrase1 in line` will work, assuming the line contains the words in exactly that order.  Are you saying you want to look for lines containing the words in any order?

Comment: Also, what's up with `for l in data[i:i:3]`?  Why not just `print (line)`?

Comment: I actually just changed it to print line. And no I want to search for three word that are independent from each other. For more transparency, I'm doing research with medical data and want to pull any different factors for the conditions. For example if the patient tested positive for the condition there is a scoring system in place so one of the things I would search for is the name of that scoring system and print the line "The patient has an "insert Score system name here" score of..." as that is how it is written in the file.

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry forgot to tag you

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of my older python scripts for parsing text.

It uses a little regx but should get you where you want to go.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import re

def readFile( fileName ):
    try:
      file myFile = open( fileName, "r")
    except IOError:
      print "There was an error reading file"
      sys.exit()
    file_text = myFile.read()
    myFile.close()
    return file_text

def writeFile( fileName, fileContent ):
    ret = 1
    try:
        file myFile = open(fileName, "w")
    except IOError:
        print "There was an error writing to", fileName
        sys.exit()
    myFile.write(fileContent)
    myFile.close()
    return ret

str     textContents  = readFile("./myfile.txt")
list    textLineList = textContents.splitlines()

for textLine in textLineList:
    if re.match("(?:word1|word2|word3)*", textLine, re.I ):
        print textLine
```

To further optimize this you could precompile the regex. But it should be a pretty fast little script already.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your:

```
if searchPhrase1 in line:
```

with

```
if any([x in line for x in ['your', 'search', 'phrases']]):
```

that will check each item in the list to see if exists in the line. any function will return true if there is at least one match.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm still too new at programming but I want it to return the line that phrase is in. Does this return as a boolean or if its true it will print that line

Comment: it returns as a boolean. Therefore if True, it will proceed to the next line inside the if block (which should be print(line))